# Battery performance of Dual SIM phone running only one SIM

Tags: battery-life, dual-sim

Does a dual-SIM Android phone running only one SIM yield almost the same battery life as a single-SIM phone?

Will both the radios be running all the time regardless of whether both the SIMs are present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_SIM):

> Battery life (talk time and standby time) of active dual-SIM mobile
>   phones is reduced, typically by about a third. For instance, Device
>   manufacturer Samsung declares a standby time for its Champ Duos E2652
>   Dual SIM phone of 476 hours when used with one SIM card and of 322
>   hours when used with two SIM cards. To compensate the shorter battery
>   life, some Dual SIM phones ship with better capacity batteries, for
>   example newer Lenovo P780 have a 4000mAh capacity.

Wikipedia also describes different types of dual-sims, such as:

- **Pseudo-Dual**
- **Dual SIM Shift**: Accepts 2 SIMS; only 1 active at a time; 1 signal bar
- **Dual SIM Dual Stand-by (DSDS)**: both active; 2 signals, but only 1 call at a time
- **Dual SIM Full Active (DSFA) Dual SIM Dual Call/Dual talk**: both active; 2 signals, and can process both calls at the same time. *I think this one would consume the most battery.*

**UPDATE 2013-09-23:** The answer to your 1st question is NO, as described in the quoted Wikipedia text above. For your 2nd question, *I don't know*, but I assume it wouldn't run since there is no SIM. Probably also the reason why it consumes lesser battery.

Comment: Agreed! But my question is what happens wen only 1 sim is used in a dual sim phone

Comment: That was answered by the first part of his answer.

Comment: The quote implies that the answer to the first part of his question is YES, not NO.

Answer (score -2):

If one SIM used on dual SIM phone, then the battery life increases. It also depends upon network range, i.e. if poor network connection then it consumes more battery than usual.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the answer addresses the questions (1 SIM usage on dual SIM vs single SIM, and if both radios running or not)